# Does Stanford NLP consider transitive/intransitive verbs when determining subject/object relationships?

Tags: nltk, stanford-nlp

Does Stanford NLP take intransitive verbs into consideration when determining relationships between nouns (subjects and objects) and verbs (transitive or intransitive)?

I ask, as this sentence contains what I believe is an intransitive verb (laughed), and therefore can not take an object.

`You have not been laughed at by us.`

I'm accessing the Stanford NLP Java binary files via NLTK with Python2.7. I'm using the `StanfordDependencyParser` to detect nominal_passive_subject (`nsubjpass`) and nominal_subject (`nsubj`).

I believe these relationships denote passive and active clauses respectively.

The mentioned sentence returns `nsubjpass`, which I understand to mean the clause is passive, but I have read that laugh/laughed is intransitive, and cannot take an object and therefore, cannot be passive.

Or is laughed not an intransitive verb, despite what I've read?
The only examples of intransitive verbs I can find are in present tense.

**EDIT**

I'll get clarification on this and post the answer, but I'm certain that 'laugh at' can be transitive.

Some people use the definition 'intransitive' as evidence that a clause can not be passive, since intransitive verbs can't have objects.

I think it's more accurate to say some verbs are intransitive because they can't take objects.]

So, 'laugh' is certainly intransitive, but 'laugh at ____' clearly takes an object, and therefore modifying 'laugh' with 'at' makes the verb transitive.

One [online dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laugh) says 'laugh at' can be transitive.

Comment: I am not an expert of English, but the sentence does seem to be in passive and the analysis by Stanford parser is correct. You should indeed be passive subject of laughed. `You is being laughed at by someone`

Comment: OK, seems that is correct @Riyaz - this website says adding 'at' to an intransitive verb can make in transitive, and therefore, accept an object. http://www.englishpractice.com/grammar/intransitive-verbs-transitive-verbs/

Comment: Please check out this: http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/activepassive.html The tense of your sentence is present perfect tense, in passive voice. I am non-native speaker, so I have been trained&retrained for some years on this now.